# insert into existing table using copy statement no working

Tags: sql, oracle

unable to insert data using below statement ,

```
copy to user/pass@db insert abc_table using SELECT
    CASE trx_desc
        WHEN 'Fulfill' THEN 'f'
        WHEN 'salary' THEN 's'
        WHEN 'name' THEN 'n'
        WHEN 'address' THEN 'a'
    END AS key_p from employee;
```

error:-
Array fetch/bind size is 500 (less if there are longs or blobs). (arraysize is 500)
Will commit when done. (copycommit is 0)
Maximum long size is 80. (long is 80)
SQL statement to execute cannot be empty or null

> > Query Run In:Query Result

Comment: Are you running this from SQL*Plus, or from a different client?

Comment: using sql developer tool.